# UISearchDisplayController Remove Gray-Out/Grey-Out [iOS7]

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I've tried playing around with this a bit but have been unable to get what I want.
I found a question online too without an answer asking the exact same question.

When search bar is enabled UISearchDisplayController greys out everything under the search bar and above the keyboard -- leaving my 'table' underneath looking kind of ugly...

How can I remove the grey-out effect?

Comment: it'd be cool if I could get something a little more constructive than edits to my tags....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {

    for (UIView *v in [[[controller.searchResultsTableView superview] superview] subviews]) {

        if (v.frame.origin.y == 64) {
            [v setHidden:YES];
        }
    }

}
```

and it works but it removes some other functionality, like cancel search by clicking on tableview....but it's better than nothing...

Comment: Not that I think this is a terribly good idea, but couldn't you keep that cancel functionality by just setting the view alpha to some really low number instead of hiding it?